# Given a set X and the distance function d(x,y), prove that (X,d) is a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I encountered this question while solving the exercises of the book "Metric Spaces" by Satish Shirali and H.L. Vasudeva.

Let $X$ denote the set of all real sequences and $x = \{x_i\}_{i \leq 1}$ and $y = \{y_i\}_{i \leq 1}$  be
arbitrary elements in X with
$$d(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}\min\left\{|x_k - y_k|,1\right\}.$$

Prove that $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

I was easily able to show that.

- $d(x,y)\geq0$
- $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
- $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$

But what I can't understand is how to approach $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$ due to the presence of the summation over all of k.

Any help/hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The summation has no effect. If $0 \le x_n \le y_n$ then $\sum_n \le \sum_n y_n $ as well.

Comment: Can you show the triangle inequality holds per summand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justify why for any triple of real numbers $x,y,z$ we have that
$$\min\{|x-y|,1\}\leq\min\{|x-z|,1\}+\min\{|z-y|,1\} $$
Conclude that for any $k$
$$\frac{1}{k^2}\min\{|x_k-y_k|,1\}\leq\frac{1}{k^2}\min\{|x_k-z_k|,1\}+\frac{1}{k^2}\min\{|z_k-y_k|,1\} $$

sum up and conclude that $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.